# testing unexpected user behaviour?

Tags: testing

I'm discovering that I'm REALLY horrible at testing, and I think to write good tests, you have to know what the user is going to do.

As an example, I've recently taken over an ajax app. It is really well written (I think) and I made some changes to implement a new feature.

When I go through the flow as we expect a user will use the app, everything works fine, but somebody else came along and just started clicking around and broke a feature. It didn't fail catastrophically, but it is definitely a bug. I can't imagine a user ever doing this, but, there is a bug in the app and I missed it in my testing.

How do you manage these sorts of cases? How do you envision anything and everything that a user could possibly do with the app and then test for it?

I understand that every app has bugs, so I'm not looking for support in how to deal with accepting that I'm not perfect.

How do you make sure you're testing as many possibilities as possible, and not just the expected behaviours?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously having a team of dedicated testers will help, and performing things like hallway testing or Bug Hunts with your development peers will provide you with some nice bugs.

But the truth is that you are simply suffering from the same thing most developers do when testing out their apps.  I wrote about it in my blog [here](http://qablog.practitest.com/2010/05/why-cant-developers-be-good-testers/), and then I wrote about some techniques you can use to improve the tests that you do [here](http://qablog.practitest.com/2010/12/teaching-programmers-to-test/).

Testing is not rocket science, but it requires some knowledge and the correct mind-set.

Good luck!

-joel

(BTW, not the same joel that Matty mentioned :-) )

Answer (score 1):

You can't anticipate what the user will do with your app. The only thing you can do is to let as many people use your app as possible and as you've already seen that'll help flush out your bugs.

Try doing some hallway testing. Do you have dedicated testers? If not, [Joel'll tell you why you should](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000067.html).

Comment: Unfortunately, dedicated testers isn't an option, I'm working for a company that doesn't have dedicated testers, and I'm just figuring out now to pad the estimates to include a significant amount of testing, but as always, everything is expected to happen yesterday.

Comment: In my (waterfall) experience there's been an approximate 1:1 development-to-QA ratio, so doubling your development estimate should put you in the right ballpark.